# Time Comparison Not Catching

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, date

I am attempting to validate importing data coming from Excel. There are cases where I get values like this: 12:00:00 AM. These should not fly. I compare them thusly:

```
if cellRange(1, CInt(fieldMapping)).Value.ToString = "12:00:00 AM" then ...
```

(cellRange is type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)

Why doesn't this comparison resolve to the 'then' statement? (Regardless of if I use .ToString or not)

Comment: Have you performed any diagnostics to check what the precise value of `cellRange(1, CInt(fieldMapping)).Value.ToString` is? Check that there aren't any non-printable characters, etc...

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(cellRange(1, CInt(fieldMapping)).Value)` <-- this will give you answer why

Comment: @JonSkeet: I literally copy/pasted "12:00:00 AM" into the Excel field to make sure there was no error.

And of course, as soon as I posted this I thought to try #12:00:00 AM# and that worked...

Comment: Copying it into Excel isn't the same as diagnosing what value you get *from the expression*. If a comparison isn't working, always diagnose things by finding out *exactly what you're comparing*.

Comment: I had done some preliminary diagnostics using Intellisense and the values shown in the hover overs there. Is what @T.S. recommended a more preferable practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison must be using '#':

```
if cellRange(1, CInt(fieldMapping)).Value.ToString = #12:00:00 AM# then ...
```